# Are there any reasons to mix WebSockets and XHR?

Tags: javascript, websocket, xmlhttprequest

I am developing a SPA - some of the features require real time bidirectional communication and some do not.

Are there any reasons for mixing XHR and Websockets here?

I suspect since I need to use WebSockets anyway, just using WebSockets for everything makes the most sense, but I'm wondering if there are any considerations I haven't taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the outcome of the XHR request is compared to the websocket connection? Websockets are generally faster by not creating a HTTP header and allow a much larger amount of data to be transferred.

From experience I would work incredibly hard on making all requests / transactions in an application the same - applying DRY principles can make your and everyone else who has to work on the project lives a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you are doing in your application. You've hit the nail in the head with this statement:

> some of the features require real time bidirectional communication and some do not.

If you need a real time full duplex communication channel then resorting to polling, long-polling, streaming, etc hacks over HTTP just to keep the same king of API everywhere might be a pain.

The same goes for websockets. If you are using websockets in one place switching everything to websockets to have the same API everywhere might turn out to be a pain.

Websocket technology is still maturing, it does not yet enjoy a full set tools or frameworks as Ajax (HTTP) does. A lot of server-side and client-side frameworks deal easily with RESTful APIs accessed over Ajax. [Not quite so for websockets yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27786935). For this reason for a large set of use cases it makes sense to stick with Ajax and use websockets only where necessary.

There is also the difference in style. In a RESTful API you are navigating resource URLs, in websocket you only have one endpoint that receives commands. If you can fit all interactions in one style then use one style, just make sure you are not loosing something from the tools/frameworks still centered around Ajax/HTTP.